# ¿Cómo utilizar un array de php en javasrcript?

Tags: php, javascript

Lo que sucede es que tengo un array en php y quisiera poder utilizarlo en javascript asi tengo el ajax:

```
$(".editarProducto").click(function () {
    $("#formulario_productos").hide();        
    var id_producto = $(this).next(".id_producto").val();
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: { id_producto: id_producto, funcion: "editarProducto" },
       success: function (r) {
           alert(r);              
        },
        error: function (r) {
            alert(r);
            alert("no se han podido obtener los parametros");
        }

    });
    $("#formulario_editar_productos").load();
    $("#formulario_editar_productos").show();
});
```

y de esta manera tengo la parte de php que me recibe los datos:

```
if (isset($_POST['funcion']) == 'editarProducto') {   

    //print_r(getProducto($_POST['id_producto'], $conn));     
    $datosProducto = array(
        "nombre_producto" => getProducto($_POST['id_producto'], $conn)['nombre_producto'],
        "id_producto" => getProducto($_POST['id_producto'], $conn)['id_producto'],
        "descripcion_producto" => getProducto($_POST['id_producto'], $conn)['descripcion_producto'],
        "tipo_producto" => getProducto($_POST['id_producto'], $conn)['id_tipo_producto']
    );   
    return $datosProducto;                
}
```

en el momento con el return no me llega nada al success del script y si le quito el return y le dejo el print con la variable me llega pero no en forma de array me llega es como string, ¿como podria hacer para poder llevar el array como tal al javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

necesitas utilizar Json en php

ejemplo:
en php

```
if (isset($_POST['funcion']) == 'editarProducto') {   

    //print_r(getProducto($_POST['id_producto'], $conn));     
    $datosProducto = array(
        "nombre_producto" => getProducto($_POST['id_producto'], $conn)['nombre_producto'],
        "id_producto" => getProducto($_POST['id_producto'], $conn)['id_producto'],
        "descripcion_producto" => getProducto($_POST['id_producto'], $conn)['descripcion_producto'],
        "tipo_producto" => getProducto($_POST['id_producto'], $conn)['id_tipo_producto']
    );   
echo json_encode($datosProducto);//arreglo que se regresara

}
```

en tu ajax recorrer con un each

```
$(".editarProducto").click(function () {
    $("#formulario_productos").hide();        
    var id_producto = $(this).next(".id_producto").val();
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        dataType : 'json',
        data: { id_producto: id_producto, funcion: "editarProducto" },
        success: function (r) {
          $.each(r, function( index, value ) {
            alert( index + ": " + value );
          });
        },
        error: function (r) {
            alert(r);
            alert("no se han podido obtener los parametros");
        }

    });
    $("#formulario_editar_productos").load();
    $("#formulario_editar_productos").show();
});
```

Comment: me funciono a la perfección, muchas gracias.